# Am new to Latex and want to make a table with 6 columns but the code below wont work. Any suggestions

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{table}[h]
\caption {Annual average concentrations of air pollutants and traffic indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation coefficients (N = 2,944). Current European air quality standards (1 year average): 40 μg/m3 (PM10); 25 μg/m3 (PM2.5); 40 μg/m3 (NO2). WHO recommendations (1 year average): 20 μg/m³ (PM10); 10 μg/m³ (PM2.5); 40 μg/m3 (NO2).}
\centering
\label {aggiungi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}

\hline
$Descriptives$&                   & $Spearman correlation coefficients$   \\\hline 
$Exposure$&     & $Mean$     & $SD$ & $5th centile$  & $Median$  & $95th centile$\\\hline

$PM10(µg\m3)$    & 20.38    & 2.42  & 16.45 & 20.49 & 24.32 \\
$PMCoarse(µg\m3)$& 6.24   & 1.08    & 4.84  & 6.07  & 8.44   \\
$PM25(µg\m3)$    & 13.55    & 0.85  & 12.5  & 13.4  & 15.29   \\ 
$PM25abs(µg\m3)$ & 1.69   & 0.17    & 1.46  & 1.67  & 1.99     \\
$NOX(µg\m3)$     & 32.7   & 7.28    & 23.83 & 31.34 & 46.66     \\
$NO2(µg\m3)$     & 18.77    & 3.83  & 13.76 & 18.28 & 25.62      \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fractions are written with a forward slash `/` rather than a backslash ```\```

Comment: Also you have ``\end{document}`` twice at the end of your code. You need to delete one of them.

Comment: The backslash means start of a command so LaTeX gets stuck on `\m` since this is not a command it knows. As side comment, you have many `$..$` with text inside. You should never use `$` to get italic since it means math mode and chance the spacing. Use `\textit{}`. For more on tables have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: You have number of mismatches in your code: number of columns (as mentioned Heiko Oberdiek in his answer), not defined character `µ`, not defined command `\m3` (probably you mean `/m^3`). How to resolve this, see Heiko answer.

Answer (score 5):

The columns are a little messed up. As far I can see, there are only six columns instead of seven. Also math mode should not be misused for typesetting plain text.

Fixed example with

- package `booktabs` for nicer rules,
- package `caption` for better spacing of the table caption above the table,
- package `siunitx` for typesetting the units and aligning the table numbers at their decimal points,
- package `lmodern` for better standard fonts,
- ...

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  group-separator={,},
  group-four-digits,
  % The input with the comma as group separator,
  % \num{2,944} (almost three thousand), can be supported by options:
  % input-decimal-markers={.},
  % input-ignore={,},
}

\DeclareSIUnit{\ugpcm}{\micro\gram\per\cubic\meter}
% u for micro (\ug is an abbreviation in package siunit for micro gram)
% g for gram
% p for per
% c for cubic
% m for meter

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  % The optional argument with a shorter version (it's still quite long)
  % for the list of tables
  \caption[Annual average concentrations of the air pollutants
    and traffic indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation
    coefficients]
  {Annual average concentrations of air pollutants and traffic
    indicators and corresponding Spearman correlation coefficients
    (N = \num{2944}).
    Current European air quality standards (1~year average):
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{25}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).
    WHO recommendations (1~year average):
    \SI{20}{\ugpcm} (PM10);
    \SI{10}{\ugpcm} (PM2.5);
    \SI{40}{\ugpcm} (NO2).}
  \label{aggiungi}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}
  }
    \toprule
    Descriptives & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Spearman correlation coefficients} \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    Exposure & {Mean} & {SD} & {5th centile}  & {Median}  & {95th centile} \\
    \midrule
    PM10 (\si{\ugpcm}) &
      20.38    & 2.42  & 16.45 & 20.49 & 24.32 \\
    PMCoarse (\si{\ugpcm}) &
      6.24   & 1.08    & 4.84  & 6.07  & 8.44  \\
    PM25 (\si{\ugpcm}) &
      13.55    & 0.85  & 12.5  & 13.4  & 15.29 \\ 
    PM25abs (\si{\ugpcm}) &
      1.69   & 0.17    & 1.46  & 1.67  & 1.99  \\
    NOX (\si{\ugpcm}) &
      32.7   & 7.28    & 23.83 & 31.34 & 46.66 \\
    NO2 (\si{\ugpcm}) &
      18.77    & 3.83  & 13.76 & 18.28 & 25.62 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I will remove units in the first column and wrote only`Exposure (\si{\micro\gram/m^3})`. By the way, you bit me for 19 seconds to load up my answer (almost the same), so I give up :)

Comment: @Zarko Wow, at the same time, three people (also Mike Renfro) have independently the same ideas to format such a table.

Comment: @Zarko I agree, that putting the unit to "Exposure" simplifies the table. But, that's up to the OP for the case there are other units around.

Comment: "Also math mode should not be misused for typesetting plain text." — +100; absolutely. However, the types of particulate matter are usually written as `$\mathrm{PM}_{10}$` and `$\mathrm{PM}_{25}$`  (note 1: is that perhaps actually PM 2.5, not 25? the former is much more common) (note 2: I'm not familiar with the "abs" variant and don't know how it's typeset). Also, "NOX" and "NO2" are chemical formulas `$\mathrm{NO}_x$` and `$\mathrm{NO}_2$`, or just `\ce{NO_{$x$}}` and `\ce{NO2}` with the `mhchem` package.

Comment: thank you guys. You are fabolous. I will try and build on this because the table now has to go to 12 columns :-)